# Error while trying to Archive an Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

Good evening guys!!

i have an xcode project that i want to publish on App Store. it`s building and running normally on a external device, but when i try to archive it, the following error occurs:

```
Ld /Users/Dado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MinhaBibliaOffline-bmkcjpxbesptrhdhnfhpudwgicip/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MinhaBibliaOffline/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MinhaBibliaOffline.app/MinhaBibliaOffline normal armv7
cd /Users/Dado/Dropbox/Sistema/MyWorkspace/Apple/MinhaBibliaOffline
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L/Users/Dado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MinhaBibliaOffline-bmkcjpxbesptrhdhnfhpudwgicip/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MinhaBibliaOffline/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/Dado/Dropbox/Sistema/MyWorkspace/Apple/MinhaBibliaOffline/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/Dado/Dropbox/Sistema/MyWorkspace/Apple/MinhaBibliaOffline/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/Dado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MinhaBibliaOffline-bmkcjpxbesptrhdhnfhpudwgicip/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MinhaBibliaOffline/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Dado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MinhaBibliaOffline-bmkcjpxbesptrhdhnfhpudwgicip/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MinhaBibliaOffline/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MinhaBibliaOffline.build/Release-iphoneos/MinhaBibliaOffline.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MinhaBibliaOffline.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-MMDrawerController -lPods-WYPopoverController -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -lsqlite3 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods-MinhaBibliaOffline -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Dado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MinhaBibliaOffline-bmkcjpxbesptrhdhnfhpudwgicip/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MinhaBibliaOffline/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MinhaBibliaOffline.build/Release-iphoneos/MinhaBibliaOffline.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MinhaBibliaOffline_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Dado/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MinhaBibliaOffline-bmkcjpxbesptrhdhnfhpudwgicip/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MinhaBibliaOffline/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MinhaBibliaOffline.app/MinhaBibliaOffline

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Dado/Dropbox/Sistema/MyWorkspace/Apple/MinhaBibliaOffline/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Dado/Dropbox/Sistema/MyWorkspace/Apple/MinhaBibliaOffline/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is my Podfile implementation

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, "7.0"

target "MinhaBibliaOffline" do

pod "AFNetworking"
pod "MMDrawerController", "~> 0.5.7"
pod "TAOOverlayHelp"
pod "WYPopoverController", "~> 0.2.2"

end
```

i have looked for a solution for hours, but still didn`t find one that worked

Comment: Looks like you didnt link your AFNEtworking pod correctly? But then your code would compile and run, so im guessing you arent using the AFNetworking package but you are still including it in your podfile?

Comment: i've just added the podfile to the question, am i missing anything?

Comment: I have the same problem. It works when doing normal builds, but fails when trying to do archive.

Answer (score 0):

i've just found an answer that worked for me.. i'll write below because it might be useful to somebody.

In my case, i had to update the "Other Linker Flags" in my project target > Build Settings.

There were wrong references to the projects added via CocoaPods:

For example:
before:       -l"Pods-AFNetworking" 
i changed to: -l"Pods-MinhaBibliaOffline-AFNetworking"

I hope this answer helps

Cheers